# Annotating single model instance (instead of queryset) in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have a Post model which contains PostVotes from users

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="PostVote")
    #other stuff
```

and the post vote can have a state of either "upvote" or "downvote" (I know I should be using enums or a bool for this before I start receiving those comments) and in many cases I need to count the total score of the object for the frontend. When I have the posts in a queryset, the following solution is working well:

```py
posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(vote=models.Sum(
    models.Case(
        models.When(postvote__state="upvote", then=1),
        models.When(postvote__state="downvote", then=-1),
        default=0,
        output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
))
```

However, there are many cases where I want to do a similar thing but instead of a queryset I have just a single instance. How do I do this? Trying the above solution gives `'Post' object has no attribute 'annotate'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you already have a Post instance, and you would like to get its score? I so, I think you could implement a computed property as follow:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="PostVote")

    @property
    def score(self):
        return sum([-1 if vote.state == 'downvote' else 1 for vote in self.postvotes.all()])
```

Note that this method will trigger extra DB queries if you didn't fetch your Post instance with `.prefetch_related('postvotes')`

Then you can use `post.score` to get the result

Another way to implement the property would be by doing a query instead:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="PostVote")

    @property
    def score(self):
        return PostVote.objects.filter(post=self.pk).aggregate(vote=models.Sum(
            models.Case(
                models.When(state="upvote", then=1),
                models.When(state="downvote", then=-1),
                default=0,
                output_field=models.IntegerField()
            )
        ))['vote']
```

Note that I didn't try any of those code, so there might be any typo/wrong variable names

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the right solution. However, when trying the computed property I'm getting the error `'Post' object has no attribute 'postvotes'`. So far I've tried also using `postvote`, `voters`, and tried adding a `related_name=` and using that, none of which have worked. Any idea where this is going wrong?

Comment: on the PostVote class, you should have something like `post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postvotes')` and use `self.postvotes.all()` (I think I forgot the `.all()` part, I'll add it through edition)

Comment: But what is about code duplication? Ie for now you have the score method implemented in 2 places: in queryset(or even manager) and in instance. In case of logic changing it will be a trick to do a change in 2 places. PS: I also face with this problem, no solution except duplication and just adding the comment in code about 2-nd place.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to add it to your query sets by default.
This should make the annotation available throughout.

1. Create a file `managers.py` inside of your app. And create the custom queryset/manager

   ```
   from django.db import models

   class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
       def annotate_vote(self):
         return self.annotate(vote=models.Sum(
             models.Case(
               models.When(postvote__state="upvote", then=1),
               models.When(postvote__state="downvote", then=-1),
               default=0,
               output_field=models.IntegerField()
           )))

   class PostManager(models.Manager):
       def get_queryset(self):
           return PostQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).\
               annotate_vote()
   ```

2. Add the new manager as inside of your model.

```
from .managers import PostManager

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PostManager()
    ...
```

3. This should give you accesss to the data like so:

`Post.objects.last().vote`